# Version control workflow with 'external' binary files

Tags: version-control, workflow

I'm working with an embedded system software project right now, and we're facing some problems dealing with some precompiled binaries living inside our repository.

We have several repositories for different parts of our project: One for the application itself, one for the OS, one for the bootloader and several libraries. All of them, except the one for our application, are shared with other teams, for other projects. We are using git (and changing is not an option right now), but I think we'd have the same problem with any VCS.

Right now, we have a precompiled binary for each of those components living inside our application repository. The idea was to speed up the build time, since the OS alone takes about 20 minutes to build from scratch and most guys work only with the application.

Problem is, there are several bugs/features in those binaries (and related application code) to be integrated at any time and, as you know, diffing and merging binaries won't work.

So, how do you guys do when you have to work with those external dependencies?

Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

One viable solution is to use an external binary repository like **[Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/)**.

- It is not linked to a VCS, meaning you can easily clean up old versions of said binaries you don't need anymore
- It is light-weight (simple HTTP client-server protocol, no need to clone *all* the repo with *all* the versioned binaries like you would with a DVCS -- git or mercurial --)